# Add an x-axis at 0 to a pyplot histogram with negative bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the histogram produced with the following code, there's no x axis at the zero level

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(left=[0,4,5],height=[-100,10,110],color=['red','green','green'],width=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting picture]

How to put it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to use `spines` to get the x-axis centered:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.bar(left=[0,4,5],height=[-100,10,110],color=['red','green','green'],width=0.1)
ax.grid(b=True)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

plt.show()
```

Which will produce the next plot:

[image]

Comment: It's a nice solution but when there's a x label it goes over the plot

Answer (score 3):

By default matplotlib does not consider the `y=0` line important. You can turn on the grid by a call such as `plt.grid()`.

An alternative used often [in the matplotlib.pylab docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) is to set a horizontal line at 0. This is done by

```
plt.axhline(0, color='black', lw=2)
```